# Question about Hölder's inequality proof

Tags: functional-analysis, holder-inequality

> Let $1 < p,q < \infty$ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}=1$. Then, for
>   $a,b \in \mathbb{K}^n$, we have:
>
> $$|\sum_i a_ib_i| \leq \Vert a \Vert_p \Vert b \Vert_q$$

My book gives the proof in the assumption that $a_i,b_i \geq 0$. Why can we make this assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because then 
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum a_{i}b_{i}\right|&\leq\sum|a_{i}||b_{i}|\\
&\leq\|(|a_{i}|)\|_{p}\|(|b_{i}|)\|_{q}\\
&=\|(a_{i})\|_{p}\|(b_{i})\|_{q}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Is this an explication why the cases where at least one $a_i, b_i < 0$ are trivial???

Comment: No matter what signs $a_{i},b_{i}$ are, the fact is that $\displaystyle\sum a_{i}b_{i}$ is dominated in absolute value by $\displaystyle\sum|a_{i}||b_{i}|$, so the sign does not matter.

Comment: How did you pass from $\sum|a_i||b_i|$ to $\Vert(|a_i|)\Vert_p\Vert(|b_i|)\Vert_q$ ? $\le$ causes doubt because by def. $\Vert f\Vert_p=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(k)|^p\right)^{1/p}$